Android studio app doesn't work after gradle update
I imported an app I'm trying to edit to my android studio (latest version), the latter required me to update the Gradle, so I did and even then I get the follow error(s):

Errors page is too long: here is a log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/101beTSA9sHMC3IUT8WaH_09Us8FDi-Ql/view?usp=drive_link
As the problem I suspect is in Gradle, here is some files that could contain the issue:

App's build.gradle

android {
    namespace 'com.example.jumperjhon'
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.breakbounce.gamezapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        }
    }
}


build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}


gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Let me know if you need to see any other files or info, I'll post them.

Please post errors as text, not images. Your error is complaining about this obsolete library, and it is unclear how your project files are attempting to pull that in. That library is no longer available via a Maven repository.

How do I implement that library? Also I added the errors in a link to a .txt file because it's really long.

The particular error is a bit strange — you might get something easier to read if you clean the project. Regardless, it seems like Gradle is having difficulty with your attempt to use com.github.d-max:spots-dialog. That library has not been updated in six years, and it was only ever distributed on JCenter. JCenter is no more, and so that library is no longer available as an artifact.
You are welcome to download the source from GitHub and add it to your project, but you will need to keep maintaining it. Or, you could look to replace your use of this particular library.

Yes, it's an old game I downloaded to renew it, I'm still unsure of how to implement that library the correct way because I updated those exact files but I'll try to do something and get back to you with the results, also I'll clean the project and see what comes up

how can I implement the library the correct way, I'm a little bit lost in this new version of android studio
